# SharePoint access denied when opening Document Library as anonumous user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

When I'm opening a document library on a SharePoint subsite, using anonymous user, it is showing 401 unauthorized error message. The permissions for the root web site and for web application are configured correctly, according to this article: http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010 Is there any other configuration or setting that has to be done for the 'Pages' Document Library in order to be available for anonymous users?

For example, I can open the root Url, but I can't open Document Library as anonymous user: 
 http://94.203.122.253:5055/English/Pages/Forms/allitems.aspx

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Have you broken the permission inheritance anywhere along the way to your document library? You'll need to ensure that you're either inheriting that permission all the way down to the library or set the anonymous user policy at that library individually.

Comment: @Benjooster yes, I've tried to set individual permissions for that "Pages" library, but it doesn't help at all, it is asking for credentials and I still got 401 unauthorized error message.

Comment: When you navigate to the library you want specifically and go to List Tools>List>Settings>List Permissions and open anonymous access do you see it listed as a permission group?

Comment: @Benjooster This question is not about list, it's about Document Library - "Pages". Yes, I've tried to break inheriting permissions for particular Document Library and configuring for unauthorized access, it didn't work.

Comment: When you navigate to the Library and open the Library Permissions do you see Anonymous Access in the ribbon?

Comment: @Benjooster yes, thats right, Anonymous Access is available in the ribbon, when I click it "View Items  -  View items in lists, documents in document libraries, view Web discussion comments, and set up alerts for lists." option is selected. This means that anonymous users should be able to view (select) library elements. But it's not working, page is asking for credentials.

Comment: That is working in my environment so I don't know what else to tell you. If you've set your Site Permissions as well as your Library permissions you should be good to go. I would try and create a new site collection as a test and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: @Benjooster Do you know if there is a way to check the actual required permissions for a particular sharepoint resource (for least or library)? Is there a command to see what permissions are expected right now to select items in the library?

Comment: You can do this in powershell or by using the "Check Permissions" box in the ribbon. PowerShell should give you all users and groups and their access level. `$urlWeb = "http://sp2010"
Get-SPUser -Web $urlWeb | select UserLogin, @{name=”Exlicit given roles”;expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name=”Roles given via groups”;expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | format-Table -auto`